# Reitit not recognising a route when it is directly navigated to in browser

Tags: clojurescript, reitit

I am trying to define some routes to use on my website. I have them defined like so:

```
(def routes
  ["/"
   [""
    {:name :home
     :controllers [{:start (fn [& params] (js/console.log "Home"))
                    :stop (fn [& params] (js/console.log "Leaving Home"))}]}]
   ["posts"
    [""
     {:name :posts
      :controllers [{:start (fn [& params] (js/console.log "Posts"))
                     :stop (fn [& params] (js/console.log "Leaving Posts"))}]}]
    (for [post blog/posts]
      [(:route post)
       {:name (:tag post)
        :controllers [{:start (fn [& params] (js/console.log (:name post)))
                       :stop (fn [& params] (js/console.log "Leaving " (:name post)))}]}])]])

(defn on-navigate [new-match]
  (when new-match
    (re-frame/dispatch [::e/navigated new-match])))

(def router
  (rf/router
   routes))

(defn init-routes! []
  (rfe/start!
   router
   on-navigate
   {:use-fragment false}))
```

This is supposed to dynamically create routes for the blog posts I define in my blog file. It works great when I start at either `localhost:8280/` or `localhost:8280/posts` and click the post link that navigates to `localhost:8280/posts/blank` (the blog post template page). If I am viewing a post (`/posts/blank`) and refresh the page, it opens to a blank screen and doesnt seem to load any of the compiled javascript. If I reload on either `/` or `/posts` it works as expected and allows me to keep browsing.

I have two questions about Reitit that I would be very grateful for some help on:

1. Why does this happen and what can I change in my route setup to fix this?
2. I currently am only able to navigate to `/posts` and not `/posts/`, how can I register the route with the extra `/` on the end as well? If I try to define two routes with the same name Reitit does not allow it.

Comment: I am encountering the same problem. Would be interested to know if you were able solve this problem.